# Get the order depends on the mac

Tags: mysql

I have the following table below and I am trying to find whether this order `ABC, DEF, GHI` as below in my stop_name column. The query works fine without this part and `mac = '30:B5:D0:06:A6:C5'`

But I want to get the result depends on the mac column. How can I fix it?

With mac I am getting:

> `#1052 - Column 'mac' in where clause is ambiguous`

**Simple:**

```
JKL
MNO
ABC
DEF
GHI
PKS
VWX
```

**Query:**

```
    SELECT b3.behaviour_id  FROM behaviour b1
    JOIN behaviour b2 ON b1.behaviour_id = b2.behaviour_id - 1
    JOIN behaviour b3 ON b2.behaviour_id = b3.behaviour_id - 1
    WHERE CONCAT(b1.stop_name, b2.stop_name, b3.stop_name) = CONCAT('ABC','DEF', 'GHI')
    AND mac = '30:B5:D0:06:A6:C5'
    order by behaviour_id
```

**behaviour table:**

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS behaviour(
 behaviour_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 mac VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 stop_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,    
 stop_distance INT(11) NOT NULL, 
 speed INT(11) NOT NULL,
 created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: Which row's `mac` column did you want to filter against?

Comment: @RowlandShaw: this one ` mac VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
`

Comment: But you're joining to that table three times, so do you want the first, second or third?

Comment: `AND b1.mac = 'xyz'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT b3.behaviour_id  FROM behaviour b1
JOIN behaviour b2 ON b1.behaviour_id = b2.behaviour_id - 1
JOIN behaviour b3 ON b2.behaviour_id = b3.behaviour_id - 1
WHERE CONCAT(b1.stop_name, b2.stop_name, b3.stop_name) = CONCAT('ABC','DEF', 'GHI')
AND b1.mac = '30:B5:D0:06:A6:C5'
order by behaviour_id
```

In the where clause add the correct table. mac is defined in b1, b2 and b3

Change `AND mac = '30:B5:D0:06:A6:C5'` to `AND b1.mac = '30:B5:D0:06:A6:C5'`